# What license should I release my code under? It contains FFmpeg binaries, code from NAudio and code from FFmpeg.Autogen

Tags: license-compatibility, license-recommendation, gpl-3, lgpl, ms-pl

I want to release my WPF Media Element based on FFmpeg on GitHub. I want to be as permissive as possible. I believe that this control could be of great help to a ton of people. Here are the links to the licenses. Hopefully someone can help me out.

- [FFmpeg build by Zeranoe](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

  - *Says all builds on this page are licensed as GPL 3.0*
- [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio)

  - *Microsoft Public License (Ms-PL)*
- [FFmpeg.Autogen](https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen)

  - *(LGPL) version 3*

If I can't release it under MIT please help me find out what license I should release this code under.

Comment: I'm kind of astonished that a good question managed to get 3 down votes. It exceeds the criteria for a license recommendation. If people do think something is wrong, please do go to meta, or even feel free to edit and improve the question yourselves! I just want to people to know that this is an excellent question for the site, and it deserves a full up vote from me.

Comment: +1. I'd really like to hear what people have against this question, because I feel this is exactly the format we want license-recommendation in.

Comment: I think that those people want AGPL everywhere, so your desire to make FFmpeg based tool as permissive as possible is just outrageous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, [the GPL 3.0 and Ms-PL are incompatible](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#ms-pl), and a work that depends on both is legally undistributable.

Fortunately, [FFmpeg is licensed under the LGPL](https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html). You will just have to find a different build, or build it yourself. The FFmpeg website has good [guides on building](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide), and external resources to help you build [exist as well](https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers).

If you make use of an LGPL build, you can distribute the product under the MIT license (and all it's parts under their respective licenses).

Comment: I assume that if I don't provide the FFmpeg binaries and just leave a readme file in the folder where binaries are supposed to go, the same logic applies, correct?

Comment: @Mario I'd have to read up on why exactly some FFmpeg binaries are LGPL and other are GPL. There seems to be something going on with GPL components or something, and I'm not sure why it would or wouldn't cause the entire thing to become GPL in the first place. I'm not sure if that would be transitive, and as to how far. I'd have to think.